# get_users meta_query: REGEXP not working for matching new lines

Tags: php, meta-query, users, regex

I have a meta field "my_meta_field" which may contain the following for these sample users:

User A

```
99999
559225
12519
```

User B

```
5020492
99999
125191
```

User C

```
194295
1199999
```

Newlines are \r\n or \n. This is on Mac for dev and Unix for server side so it is probably \n.

If the target number is **99999** then I should get a match for User A and B. Need to be careful not to match situations like User C where a number has the target inside "1199999"

Matching start of line, or \n, or \r\n at the beginning should take care of this.

```
$user = get_users( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'my_meta_field',
            'value' => '(^|\\n|\\r\\n)99999',
            'compare' => 'REGEXP',
        ),
    ),
) );
```

Unfortunately this only matches User A correctly. It doesn't match User B. This regular expression works perfectly in tools such as https://regex101.com/.

I've tried different formats such as: `(^|\n|\r\n)99999`

Thank you in advance if anyone knows what's wrong here.

Comment: You Regex doesn't even work in the tool you provided, for second user.

Comment: @Sumit That's the PHP syntax, the expression I used in regex101.com was  (^|\n|\r\n)99999.

Update: Solved the problem (added answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem and also fixed a bug in the regex.

Final code:

`'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'my_meta_field',
        'value' => "(^|\n|\r\n)99999($|\n|\r\n)",
        'compare' => 'REGEXP',
    ),
),`

The problem here was Wordpress was adding extra backslashes on the special characters. By wrapping the expression in double quotes, this problem was solved.

Also added end of string/new line capturing on the tail end of the target value.